# 1C 8.3. Как в печатную форму перенести презентацию powerpoint?

Tags: 1с

Если excel можно было просто выделить, скопировать, вставить и переделать, то с powerpoint так не особо получается.
Выглядит примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно перенести такую презентацию в печатную форму?

Comment: Не ясна суть, что именно должно быть на выходе. Что значит перенести в печатную форму? Печатная форма должна быть похожа на презентацию?! Так же неясно пример с Excel описан: что можно было скопировать, зачем редактировать и т.п.

Comment: Согласен с Sagittarius; Если необходимо из 1С создать презентацию см:  https://infostart.ru/public/425588/